# How to use two constructors?

Tags: c++

I have a code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class AbstractValueC{
        private:
                long age = 0;
                int abs;
                bool spec = false;
        public:
                AbstractValueC() {
                        abs = 0;
                }
                AbstractValueC(int& a, bool b = false){
                        abs = *a;
                        spec = b;
                }
                AbstractValueC(int a, bool b = false){
                        abs = a;
                        spec = b;
                }
                int get_value() const {
                        return abs;
                }
                long get_age(){
                       return age;
                }
 };

int main(){
    vector<AbstractValueC> v;
    int init = 1;
    int next = 2;
    v.push_back(AbstractValueC(std::move(init)));
    cout << "I have created first v element." << endl;
    v.push_back(AbstractValueC(std::move(next)));
    cout << "I have created second v element." << endl;

    std::vector<AbstractValueC> result;
      for (auto a : v) {
          int pre = a.get_value();
          result.push_back(AbstractValueC(pre));
        }
    cout << "I have created result." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me how to solve the error of

```
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
                         abs = *a;
                                ^
```

and the error

```
call of overloaded ‘AbstractValueC(int&)’ is ambiguous
           result.push_back(AbstractValueC(pre));
                                              ^
```

I actually have a custom type (`Abs`) in place of `int` for the `abs` member in my actual code. Also the requirement is that I cannot call the default constructor of `Abs` in main. I can use `abs = Abs::null;`. So please suggest a solution that avoid calling the default constructor for `Abs` if I replace `int` with `Abs` in the class definition.

Comment: You declared abs are an integer but assign value is a pointer

Answer (score 3):

### invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

```
AbstractValueC(int& a, bool b = false){
                        abs = *a;
                        spec = b;
                }
```

Argument `a` is an int reference, not a pointer, so you can't dereference as `*a`.

The code should be `abs = a;`

### call of overloaded ‘AbstractValueC(int&)’ is ambiguous

As @strom points out in the comments, you have 2 similar constructors:

```
AbstractValueC(int& a, bool b = false)
AbstractValueC(int a, bool b = false)
```

Which the compiler cannot readily distinguish between. You should get rid of one of them.

Comment: So should I use `abs = a;` for both `int& a` and `int a`?

Comment: The `int&` and `int` result the same signature.

Comment: What they do is different, but it is ambiguous if you pass an `int` var into it. The compiler cannot tell which one should be called.

Comment: Also, it should be a `const int&` if you're not modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you are using two constructors with the same signature :

How does the compiler choose between using :

```
AbstractValueC v=AbstractValueC(value);//int constructor
```

And

```
AbstractValueC v=AbstractValueC(value);//reference constructor
```

When you have

```
Int value = 0;//for example
```

To get rid of this error(ambigueous constructor call) you could either change one of the constructors or replace your reference constructor with a pointer constructor

To change the constructor to a pointer, you need to create a value pointer in your class and create a contructor:

```
// in class declaration
Int *pointerValue = nullptr;

AbstractValueC(int* pointer, bool b = false);

// implementation
AbstractValueC::AbstractValueC(Int *pointer, bool b=false) {
    pointerValue=pointer;
}
```

Comment: how to change  a reference constructor with a pointer constructor?

Comment: Refer to above edited question for more details about that